# how can I make it easier to move the browser window?

Tags: gnome

I am running the latest ubuntu but It is hard to get the curser to move a browser windows out of the way. I am using the arcvamarin theme I think

Answer (score 0):

Firstly such a theme does not exist - i cannot check if it's actually a theme related issue. Theme's name may be misspelled (check it).

Secondly - specify your problem more precisely - do you mean minimizing the browser (firefox, I suppose) window? If yes and it actually IS theme related problem - why wouldn't you simply change your theme? Otherwise you can always try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> shortcut (or customize it to anything you want in Ubuntu settings). The <kbd>0</kbd> key is from numpad on default.

If by "moving browser windows out of the way" you mean just moving the unmaximized window around your desktop - you can either also use similar shortcuts but with <kbd>1</kbd>,<kbd>2</kbd>,<kbd>3</kbd>... instead of <kbd>0</kbd>, or install software like *CompizConfig Settings Manager* (look for it in *Ubuntu Software Center*). It enables you to customize the way you interact with windows, for instance with <kbd>alt</kbd> button held you can move your window around by simply clicking (anywhere inside the window) and dragging it around.

Another way to install Compiz - paste that into the terminal window:

```
sudo apt-get install compiz compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-fusion-plugins-extra compiz-fusion-plugins-main compiz-plugins
```